# Hi guys, I am having a hard time with the new version of Next.js (14). Does it support API routes or did they delete the feature?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to make an API in the new version of Next.js (14), but it looks like the new version does not support that. I made a folder (api) and a file (hello.js) that contains API code, but it did not work. Here is a screenshot of my code and the error message: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZYY.png] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7SwH.png]

I tried to make an API in the new Next.js version and I had a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**

> I tried to make an API in the new Next.js version and I had a problem.

**Cause :**

> Versions of NextJS  from `13.2` have a different way of writing API in app router.
> You need to export an async function named by the HTTP verbs: GET,
> HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE, and PATCH.

**Solution :**

In your `api` folder, make a folder named `hello` (folder name = api name).

Inside 'hello' folder make a file named as `route.js`, & paste below code.

```
export async function GET(request) {
    return Response.json({ text: "hello" }, { status: 200, statusText: "Its OK !" })
}
```

*You can also use NextResponse & NextRequest. (Read more in links given below.)*

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request) {
    return NextResponse.json({ text: "hello" }, { status: 200, statusText: "Its OK !" })
}
```

***Please Read :***

- **Next.js 13.2 Custom Route Handlers** : https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2#custom-route-handlers
- **Route Handlers :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers
- **Request :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request
- **Response :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response
- **Response.json()** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json_static
- **NextRequest :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request
- **NextResponse :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response

> ***If you still have doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: PS: The old API code like this:

export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}

still works, but only in Pages Router.